# How to use setState in Flutter WITHOUT user interaction

Tags: flutter

I'm a Newbie in Flutter, I create an App with:

1. An AppBar with Title Text: 'Count: ' + intCount, in which intCount is a global integer.
2. Another thread 'work', that increment intCount each second.  (I did this in order to simulate: some [variables] in the App may be changed by, for example, socket.io communications, without any user interaction)

So, my problem is, how can I change the AppBar Title Text when intCount changes? (In other words, where should I use setState?)

My main.dart is as follow: (the package threading can be added by add 'threading:' under the 'dependecies' of the file 'pubspec.yaml', and click 'Tools' -> 'Flutter' -> 'Flutter Packages Get' in Android Studio)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import "package:threading/threading.dart";

var intCount = 0;

void main() {
  var thread = new Thread(work);
  thread.start();

  runApp(mainApp());
}

class mainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}
class _MainAppState extends State<mainApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              'Count: ' + intCount.toString()),
        ),
        body: HelloRectangle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


work() async{
  print('Work Begins ...');
  while (true) {
    await Thread.sleep(1000);
    intCount += 1;
    print('Count: ' + intCount.toString());
  }
}


class HelloRectangle extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        height: 300.0,
        width: 300.0,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in the following screen capture, the intCount changes as shown in the console, but the AppBar Title Text does not change:

[image]

Comment: Did you end up solving this? The only answer right now is "don't call from outside". I want to call outside though.

Comment: yes, now I'm using Redux to handle the state management of flutter app, I can now re-render any widget outside that widget without calling setstate inside that widget.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working, don't call from outside of class, here the solution.

```
int _count = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    var thread = new Thread(count);
    thread.start();
    _initData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void count() async {
    while (true) {
      setState(() {
        _count += 1;
      });
      await Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
 appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(_count.toString()),
        ),
```

The above CORRECT ANSWER provided by Mr. Satish Soni,  I would like to include the answer inside my original codes as follow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import "package:threading/threading.dart";

var intCount = 0;

void main() {
  runApp(mainApp());
}

class mainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}
class _MainAppState extends State<mainApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    var thread = new Thread(work);
    thread.start();
    super.initState();
  }

  void work() async{
    print('Work Begins ...');
    while (true) {
      await Thread.sleep(1000);
      setState(() {
        intCount += 1;
      });
      print('Count: ' + intCount.toString());
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              'Count: ' + intCount.toString()),
        ),
        body: HelloRectangle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After Satish's answer is included, the correct intCount will be shown in the consoles as well as in the AppBar.

Which means that, to my understanding, by using Flutter, anything 'happens in the world outside the Stateful Widget', will not be reflected inside the widget.

In order to let the widget 're-render' itself when something happens to its binding variable outside the widget, I tried the following work around:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import "package:threading/threading.dart";

var intCount = 0;

void main() {
  var thread = new Thread(work);
  thread.start();

  runApp(mainApp());
}

class mainApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}
class _MainAppState extends State<mainApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    var thread2 = new Thread(work2);
    thread2.start();

    super.initState();
  }


  void work2() async{
    while (true) {
      await Thread.sleep(100);
      setState(() {
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              'Count: ' + intCount.toString()),
        ),
        body: HelloRectangle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}



void work() async{
  print('Work Begins ...');
  while (true) {
    await Thread.sleep(1000);
    intCount += 1;
    print('Count: ' + intCount.toString());
  }
}


class HelloRectangle extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        height: 300.0,
        width: 300.0,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the thread 'work' changes the global variable intCount, to simulate the situation that this variable is changed by something (may be timer/socket/database etc) outside the widget.

Then, I use another thread work2 inside the widget to 'setState' itself every 100ms.

Ok, I know, this is stupid, waste of resources, response is slow (100ms)......  But this is also the best work around I can think of.  Actually, I was trying to do something like 'Dynamic Binding' (e.g. like those in AngularJS), or 'Force Re-rendering' (e.g. App went to background and came back a few minutes later, something has changed).

Anyway, thanks again for Satish Soni.

Comment: Hi satish, thanks for your quick response, it is said that 'setState is not defined'.  I believe the other thread 'work' is not part of the widgets.  BTW, it seems that there shouldn't be an ';' after '1'.

Comment: Actually, this not the way what you are doing, the dart is not multithread language, it does not support multithread. while(){}, is kind of infinite loop, you can use some animation AnimationBuilder(),

Comment: But the main problem of my question is, the intCount IS NOT changed by any widgets, but changed by other process such as, for example, the socket.io 'onMessageArrive'.  How can the AnimationBuilder re-render the page if the state of itself is not changed at all?

Comment: You should call the setState inside the scope of the StatefulWidget and calling it when you increment the variable, so inside the work() function that you have to put inside the class of the StatefulWidget and not outside (this is why you get an error).

Comment: You did not get my answer, no matter define variable anywhere. But you have to call setState(); to change build again and again.

Comment: I know I need to call setState, my problem is I don't know when to call setState, for example, I use Flutter to create a 2 players ONLINE game, say, player A and player B, in player A screen, the position of player A can be changed by setState, but the position of player B, is controlled by player B's mobile phone, and I don't know when to call setState to update player B's position.